# Which kind of join do I need to use here?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For every row in table Y, I need a copy of the current row in Table X, taking field 1 from Table Y.

**Table X**

```
Field 1     Field 2
 null          A
 null          B
 null          C
```

**Table Y**

```
Field 1
   1
   2
   3
```

**Desired output**

```
Field 1     Field 2
   1           A
   1           B
   1           C
   2           A
   2           B
   2           C
   3           A
   3           B
   3           C
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a `cross join`:

```
select y.field1, x.field2
from x cross join
     y;
```

Comment: Perfect! I was going through all the joins I could think of. Completely missed out Cross Join. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an unconditional select of both tables without matching ids

Something like

```
select tableY.column1, tableX.column2
from tableY, tableX
order by tableY.column1 asc, tableX.column2 asc
```

should do it.

BTW. Was this a school question, because then I should not have answered this.

Comment: Haha, Don't worry, I'm not a student :) Just re-wrote the query to simplify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT #Tabley.Field1 , #TableX.Field2
FROM #TableX ,#Tabley
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.